# AuthorizedFeignClient with custom role for JHipster microservices with UAA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster, feign

I am working on some microservices generated with JHipster 6.1.0, which use the JHipster UAA server for authentication.

The project consists of the following microservices:

- [gateway](https://github.com/iroCheese/demo-gateway)
- [UAA server](https://github.com/iroCheese/demo-uaa)
- [publicMicroservice](https://github.com/iroCheese/demo-publicMicroservice) (microservice which allows unauthenticated access to /api/)
- [restrictedMicroservice](https://github.com/iroCheese/demo-restrictedMicroservice) (microservice which should only be accessible to publicMicroservice)

I am trying to perform requests from publicMicroservice to restrictedMicroservice using an AuthorizedFeignClient.

This works as expected when I leave SecurityConfiguration in restrictedMicroservice like this `.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()`

and use the default client-id and client-secret in application-dev.yml of publicMicroservice

```
security:
  client-authorization:
    access-token-uri: http://uaa/oauth/token
    token-service-id: uaa
    client-id: internal
    client-secret: internal
```

However I would rather have publicMicroservice authenticate as a custom user with a custom role `ROLE_MYMICROSERVICE` because just using `.authenticated()` also allows regular logged in users to access the resources of restrictedMicroservice.

Therefor I created a new user "mymicroservice" with the same password hash as the admin user and the custom role in the UAA .csv files.
I changed the application-dev.yml of publicMicroservice as follows:

```
security:
  client-authorization:
    access-token-uri: http://uaa/oauth/token
    token-service-id: uaa
    client-id: mymicroservice
    client-secret: admin
```

and SecurityConfiguration in restrictedMicroservice like this:

```
// .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
.antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_MYMICROSERVICE")
```

Now apparently authentication fails in the UAA server, which claims that the credentials are bad.

```
2019-07-12 17:39:17.638 DEBUG 29485 --- [ XNIO-1 task-56] c.m.myapp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Enter: com.mycompany.myapp.repository.CustomAuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-07-12T15:39:17.638Z, principal=mymicroservice, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffa64e: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.1.111; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=Bad credentials}]]
```

I made sure that the credentials work in the gateway webApp so I can rule out typos. As the [JHipster documentation](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-uaa/) doesn't go into much detail about how the client-id and client-secret is used, I am now stuck and don't known how to tackle the problem.

I created Github repositories (see links above) to reproduce the problem and would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think you need to declare a client with client-credential-flow in the uaa for inter-microservice communication. Also, I suggest to use oauth2RestTemplate rather than feign.